# What image sizes do you use in Xcode for iPhone5 Storyboard

Tags: xcode, graphics, storyboard, iphone-5

When creating an iPhone5 storyboard, what images do you use inside of Xcode.  Since the iPhone5 is retina only, then all of your graphics have to be doubled, and yet the coordinates are all 1/2 of that.

So if I have an image in the middle of the screen that is 50 x 50 in Xcode, then my iPhone5 image has to be 100x100.  If I name that image image100.png do I still create a UIImageView on the screen at 50x50 and give it the image100.png.  That appears to work, and if so is the rule that when creating an iPhone5 Storyboard that you just have to remember to cut all of your heights and widths by 2?

Comment: @justdan0227 Accept answers that helped you.

Comment: Ok, I'm sorry but I don't see where I do that

Comment: Sorry found it.  I never knew about the check mark.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes that's the rule.

It's all a matter of getting used to the idea of resolution independence. Points are not pixels. On the iphone5, we want image resolutions of 2 pixels per point, on a nonretina screen we want our image resolutions at 1 pixel per point.

Comment: Right so again I use the image100.png which is 100x100 and place it into an imageview that is 50x50. Correct?  My issue is that my graphics artist is giving me graphics that are 97 x 43 which is the "retina version" and I can't create an imageview that will contain it on an iPhone5 without having it aspect fill.

Comment: Yes. The imageView frame and bounds are measured in points, not pixels. Ultimately they are independent of the size of the contained image.

Comment: Your artist should preferably work in even numbers for retina assets. Otherwise you are going to have to set 1/2-point dimensions for your frames, and the numbers won't map to non-retina assets. I am not sure what you really mean by an iphone5-only storyboard. Do you mean the project will only be used on an iphone5? Or just that you have 2 storyboards, one for each iphone screen size (that is points, not pixels!). The aspect fill issue shouldn't be affected by any of that.

Comment: Actually he has different graphics for an iPhone5 to take advantage of the extra space.